# why react native Manifest merger failed after adding react-native-in-app-review?

Tags: android, react-native, android-manifest, npm-package

getting below error after integrating react-native-in-app-review

```
Execution failed for task ':app:processProdDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.versionCode@value value=(20001) from [com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:17-38
        is also present at [com.google.android.play:core:1.9.1] AndroidManifest.xml:17:85-106 value=(10901).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml to override.
```

Trying to implement in-app-review using below for android.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-in-app-review

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34821
or
https://github.com/MinaSamir11/react-native-in-app-review/issues/7
or
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34827
The link above will assist you in finding the answer.